# AutoMapper: Create universal wrapper for mapping engine

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to create an universal wrapper for AutoMapper mapping engine. My final goal is to be tied to an interface.

```
public interface IMappingEngine
{
    TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source);
}
```

I will resolve it with DI.

Then I create an implementation of this interface based on AutoMapper `MappingEngine`.

```
public class AutoMapperMappingEngine : IMappingEngine
{
    private readonly ConfigurationStore configurationStore;
    private readonly MappingEngine mappingEngine;

    public AutoMapperMappingEngine()
    {
        this.configurationStore = new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.Mappers);
        this.RegisterMappings();
        this.configurationStore.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        this.mappingEngine = new MappingEngine(this.configurationStore);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method registers alternate mappings for already existing mappings.
    /// </summary>
    private void RegisterMappings()
    {
        // some code
        // this.configurationStore.CreateMap<>
    }

    public TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source)
    {
        TDestination mappingResult = this.mappingEngine.Map<TDestination>(source);
        return mappingResult;
    }
}
```

But I stuck with a problem. What happen if I will need more than two different mappings for the same pair of types?

```
IMappingEngine autoMapperMappingEngine;
// Initialize autoMapperMappingEngine
FooModel result;

if(firstCondition)
{
    result = autoMapperMappingEngine.Map<FooEntity, FooModel>(entity);
} 
else
{
    if(secondCondition)
    {
         result = autoMapperMappingEngine.Map<FooEntity, FooModel>(entity);
    }
    else
    {
         result = autoMapperMappingEngine.Map<FooEntity, FooModel>(entity);
    }
}
```

If I register a few different mappings in sequence inside of `RegisterMappings` the last mapping will overlap the rest. Could you give some advises how to implement what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Instance API instead;

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Static-and-Instance-API

This involves creating a configuration and using that to map, so that you can have multiple configurations... You will of course have to extend your interface

Comment: The problem is that you saw only my simple example of a problem I stuck with. My general project has a lot of layers. On each layer I use `Mapper.CreateMap<>` method to register my mappings. I need to use `MappingEngine` in some special cases when I need an alternate mappings.

Comment: @JosephKatzman I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean? Using a configuration instance should certainly meet any requirements, could you try explain why this wouldn't work? What special cases? Why are they not covered by having multiple configurations with different mappings?

Comment: I have a big project. I can't rewrite parts of code which are depend on static  `Mapper.CreateMap<>`. That's why I use `MappingEngine`. I know that I should rewrite my project by using interface which I describe above. Let's assume that it is impossible to rewrite it. It is a challenge for me ;) There another ways to implement what I want?

Comment: @JosephKatzman You can extend the interface with an optional parameter for the mapping config, and then do it the way you are currently where one is not required. This way you only need to change code which supports the new scenario, can leave all the old code that doesn't need to do this, and have the best of both worlds! I can't see any way round changing it somehow sadly...